# For religious reasons, which plants should never be planted inside the house or even close to the house?

Tags: belief, plants

I have been told that, for religious reasons, some plants must never be planted inside your house, or inner courtyard or even close the house, as in front-yard/backyard.

A pundit had specifically mentioned 5 plants but I can't recall them.

The pundit also emphasized, the branches of these plants must not touch the house or house boundary wall at all, though they may be planted towards outside perimeter if the front-yard/backyard is large.

Would you know which plants and why?

Comment: You will get all your answers and more in the "VASTU SHASTRA" Try it and see...

Answer (score 2):

According to religious and scientific reason [Mango](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mango) tree, [Peepal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ficus_religiosa) tree , [Neem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azadirachta_indica) tree are good in nearby. But,

> **Thorny Plants** - Thorny plants should not be planted near the house. Cactus should not be planted at all. Thorny plants other than roses have a negative energy. Ideally, all thorny plants should be
>   pulled up and destroyed. The reason could be that the thorns can hurt
>   you when you brush past them so be careful.
>
> **Creepers** – Creepers or other plants should not be grown along-side the building wall as support their clingers slowly creep into tiny
>   cracks in the walls and gradually widen them as they grow, causing
>   damage and seepage of water through the walls. Creepers should only be
>   grown in a garden, and they should have their own independent
>   supports. A creeper like a Money plant can be grown within the house
>   but should not be grown outside, using a tree for support.
>
> **Flower Pots** - Flower pots should not be kept on the compound wall facing the North, East or North-East as they will block the useful
>   morning sunlight coming in from these directions. Flower pots and
>   decorative plants can be placed on the ground in these directions, but
>   they should not grow taller than 3 feet.

Fore more information refer [here](http://astrologyreadings.tumblr.com/post/37254988193/what-trees-should-be-planted-in-a-house-garden).

Comment: Can you please update the answer to focus only on religious reasons. Please include references for your answer.

Comment: -1 for `Thorny plants other than roses have a negative energy`. Will remove downvote if you define negative energy.

Comment: This question is more vaastu related and less related to 'religion'. Just because a pandit suggests that some plants are inauspicious does not make them a part of religion. It is actually vaastu combined into religion. Answer by Hardik Vyas is not incorrect in my opinion.

Comment: @ASomani I have no idea about Vaastu, so I can't comment on that but I am seeking an answer from the religious viewpoint. The pundit explicitly mentioned 5 plants from a religious viewpoint because they bring bad luck.